# Pre Rendering tile using render_list command is extremely slow

Tags: openstreetmap, rendering, osm2pgsql

I have created a OSM tile serving server using osm2pgsql with entire asia tiles. I am using Ubuntu 18.04, 32 CPU cores, 132 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD. This I believe is a reasonable hardware. Now, I feel that de facto rendering of tiles is extremely slow for production environments when i cross zoom level 5-6. So in order to circumvent it I have started pre-rendering for zoom level 1-15.

I have used : **render_list -m default -a -z 0 -Z 15 --num-threads=20**

I feel that this process is extremely slow.

Here is a sample output :

```
Nov 02 14:56:02 test-virtual-machine renderd[19184]: DEBUG: Sending render cmd(3 default 8/104/112) with protocol version 2 to fd 31
Nov 02 14:56:40 test-virtual-machine renderd[19184]: DEBUG: DONE TILE default 8 104-111 128-135 in 117.281 seconds
Nov 02 14:56:40 test-virtual-machine renderd[19184]: DEBUG: Sending render cmd(3 default 8/104/128) with protocol version 2 to fd 32
Nov 02 14:56:54 test-virtual-machine renderd[19184]: DEBUG: DONE TILE default 8 104-111 136-143 in 129.875 seconds
```

As you can see quite frequently its taking 100 sec+ for iterations. Also it has been running for more than 3 hours now and I only see /var/lib/mod_tile/default with 109MB size and 929 files. I am assuming this is where the tiles will be extracted by the render_list process.

Is this standard behavior or are there things I can do to fasten the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating indices as per the following sql script helped speed up the performance.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto/master/indexes.sql

The server is still pre rendering and needless to say the time increases exponentially with every zoom level. But its considerably after after running the above script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Ubuntu 18.04, 32 CPU cores, 132 GB RAM, **1 TB HDD**.

> Is this standard behavior or are there things I can do to fasten the process?

Swith to SSD, preferably NVMe. Many processes in OSM rendering and database processing need fast random access.